# Help determing an $A$-module automorphism of $E \times F$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

The following question is based on material from the first section on module theory in Hungerford's algebra and is a possible test question for a qualifying exam in linear algebra.  I have been able to prove the first part of the problem which is an easy exercise in checking bijectivity of the map $h$ defined below.  I am stuck on the second part of the question.

Given two $A$-modules $E,F$  and a linear map $u: E \rightarrow F$.

$h:E \times F \rightarrow E \times F$ is an automorphism of $E \times F$ given by $h(x,y) = (x,y-u(x))$.  Suppose further that there is a linear mapping $v:F \rightarrow E$ and an $ a \in E$ such that $v(u(a)) = a$.

> Show there exists an automorphism $w:E \times F \rightarrow E \times F$ such that $w(a,0) = (0,u(a))$

Is the map given by $w(x,y):=(x-v(u(x)),x+u(y))$  or $w(x,y):=(x-v(u(x)),u(x)-y)$ the correct automorphism?  I am having trouble figuring out where to put the linear map $v$ even after considering the image of (a,0) and (0,a) under various combinations of $h$ and $h^{-1}$ with $v$.

Comment: You have great chances for the Least Motivated Question of the Year  Award! :)

Comment: You probably shouldn't use $a$ as both a distinguished element and a general element of $E$. In particular, I don't know whether the condition in the box is about one element or all of them, given what comes afterward.

Comment: Your first option for $w$ does not make sense, because you have an $x$ in the second component. On the other hand, your second option for $w$ vanishes on $(a,u(a))$, so it is clearly not an isomorphism (presumably, $a$ is not zero...)